# Change boolean value with hidden_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a **MEMBER** column to **USER**.

I am trying to change the value of MEMBER to false via a hidden_field when submit a form.

But the value of the hidden_field does not work!
Why ?

**db**

```
class AddMemberToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :users, :member, :boolean, default: true
  end
end
```

**users/views/form**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name,:html => { :id => "new_user_1"}, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        ...
        <%= f.hidden_field :member, value: false %>
        <%= f.submit "S'inscrire" %>
 <% end %>
```

**users/registrations_controllers**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
  private
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :member)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fullname,:avatar,:job, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please you English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: instead of passing values as `true/false`. Try passing it as `0/1`

Comment: Sorry sawa, i don't speak english .. 

And @GaganGupta thank you very much it works with 0 and 1 ! It was as simple as that .. big thanks !

Comment: ohh :D, I am glad it worked. Just check the database whether it is updating the correct values as true and false for 1 and 0.

Comment: @GaganGupta Yes I check and 0 or 1 update my database correctly with true or false ! :) Thx !!!

Comment: ohh, I am glad. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hidden_field` behaves as a hidden `text_field` hence, it expects a string value. I would suggest you to pass a text value which you can consider false inside a controller.

either use values `0/1`

OR

another way would be:

example:

```
def sign_up_params
  params[:user][:member] = params[:user] && params[:user][:member] == '0' ? false : true
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :member)
end
```

you can handle this manually inside your controller.